# How to beat Typhon with a Wanderer?

Tags: titan-quest-anniversary-edition

As per question title, what is the best way to kill it?

I'm level 31 Wanderer and am having a hard time with him. My current build is:

[image]

[Titan Calc](http://www.titancalc.com/TitanCalc.asp?mastery=Wanderer&master1=4&master2=0&sa=3&m1=32-2-16-2-4-1-5-0-1-1-1-5-0-1-4-9-1-3-4-0-1-0&m2=0)

Comment: Just a point of clarification - are you asking about how to specifically beat him with a wanderer? If so, it might be useful to provide some more information about your current build

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein Thanks for feedback, current build added.